# pyperclip has no attribute copy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyperclip

When i run this code

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('German')
pyperclip.paste()
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Windows/System32/pyperclip.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyperclip
  File "C:/Windows/System32\pyperclip.py", line 2, in <module>
    pyperclip.copy('German')
AttributeError: module 'pyperclip' has no attribute 'copy'
```

I have installed pyperclip using pip
I have tried reinstalling Pyperclip but it does nothing.

Comment: You've named your own script `pyperclip.py`, so *that* is what you're importing. Also, why on earth are your scripts in `System32`?

Answer (score 6):

You called your module `pyperclip` by naming your file `pyperclip.py`. Therefore, your `import pyperclip` is actually a recursive import (importing your own module) and will not work.

To avoid this, just don't name your module the same as a library you use.

Answer (score 1):

instead of pyperclip I have decided to use os:

```
os.system("echo '%s' | pbcopy" % STRING_NAME_HERE
```

Comment: I have used different function and tried to overpass it

Comment: It’s worth noting that pbcopy is macOS-specific and wouldn’t work on e.g. Windows (which is what the poster is using).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend start reading **@nneonneo** answer first and if the below solutions did not fix the problem, try this one:

- In the same directory I noticed that I have `paperclip.py` file. I **just renamed it** and it stopped showing `circular import` error

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, Have you install pyper clip module or not. if you have not install pyperclip module then it will not work

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer